# Come across a post that needs flagging but ran out of flags

Tags: discussion, flags, rate-limiting

Say if I come across a post that needs to be flagged. For example, it is SPAM, Rude or Offensive or Not An Answer. Then I realise I have reached my daily flag limit.

What should be done to alert moderators of the post and delete it?

Is there any reason to worry?

Answer (score 7):

First of all, there is not much too worry.

Here are some reasons for what you can do/why you shouldn't worry:

**Bumped to the Homepage** - Another user will most likely see it as it will be bumped to the Home Page and they can flag it.

**Review Queues** - Most likely this will be a new user posting this. A person will need to review their post and will most likely flag it.

**Charcoal HQ Chat**:

*There should be more eyeballs/ready-to-flag people in Charcoal HQ. The post may have already been caught by their spam detection bot, SmokeDetector. If it hasn't been caught, you can bring up the post there and they will manually report it for flagging.* (Credit to @Jenayah)

**Chat** - If necessary, you can ping the moderators in the Site Chat and make them aware of the situation.

In general, it will be dealt with and there is not much to worry!

Comment: Drop by [Charcoal HQ chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq) first rather than Site Chat, maybe? Site mods can't always be there (well, Charcoal guys either, sure), but still, there should be more eyeballs/ready-to-flag people in Charcoal HQ. Plus, lots of people there can report it to Smokey, adding it to the balcklist, etc etc. (and you can also check whether it has already been reported; if that's the case, this is falling back to #1)